# Yii DropdownList prompt

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

I have this dropdownlist, but it doesnt take prompt or empty as the default value, it always takes the last value of the $list, why can it be?

```
        $models = ZfInfraestructuras::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'infraestructura_nombre'));
        $list = CHtml::listData($models, 
                'infraestructura_id', 'infraestructura_nombre');

        echo CHtml::dropDownList('infraestructuras', $models, 
              $list,
              array('prompt' => 'Selecciona Infraestructura'));
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static string dropDownList(string $name, string $select, array $data, array $htmlOptions=array ( ))
```

check the select parameter

http://yiiapi.com/CHtml#dropDownList-detail

Comment: Thanks! You made me find the solution :D